# value only in first row of new category, how to fill missing values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to clean data from an Excel file with PANDAS.

[image]

I want to fill the missing values from the category and subcategory columns.

[image]

I was thinking a for loop, but I not sure how I would do that. Anyone know or have a better idea to manage this data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has a handy `.fillna()` method that helps here. Assuming your data is stored in `spreadsheet.csv`, you can just use the code below. The `ffill` method is an abbreviation for "forward fill" - meaning that it will go down each column and fill a missing value with the value above it.

```
df = pd.read_csv('spreadsheet.csv')
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Alternatively, if you want to manually specify a fill value for each column, you can pass a dictionary into `.fillna()` using the column names for keys, and replacement for values. For example:

```
df.fillna({'Category': 'new category value', 
           'SubCategory': 'new subcategory', 
           'Product': "No product"})
```